# Is it possible to use a like statement in the first part of an IIF statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on an SQL server (2008) and can't seem to use a LIKE statement within the boolean part of an IIF statement.

The following query runs correctly, so the syntax of my LIKE statement seems fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.IpPbxCDR
WHERE dbo.IpPbxCDR.OriginationNumber LIKE '+31%'
```

However when running the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.IpPbxCDR
WHERE IIF(dbo.IpPbxCDR.OriginationNumber LIKE '+31%','0' + Right([dbo.IpPbxCDR].[OriginationNumber],9), Replace([dbo.IpPbxCDR].[OriginationNumber],'+','00')) = '0201234567'
```

I get the following error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'.

Am I doing something wrong, or is what I'm doing not possible on SQL server 2008?

Oh, one other thing, if I add the table as a linked table in Access, and run the query there, everything works fine, however I think in this situation Access does the evaluation and not SQL Server.

Edit: (Resolved) Alright it looks like prior to version 2012 one needs to use the Case statement. As always, thanks for your input stackoverflow users, yall are amazing!

Comment: Wouldn't you put the IF part to `SELECT *, IF()... FROM` ?

Comment: `IIF` was new in [SQL Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx)

Comment: No, because I need evaluate the results of the IIF statement. (What I'm doing is comparing phone numbers, however the source I'm doing this from doesn't give me phone numbers in a "+31XXXXXXXX" format, but in the dutch national format. The IIF statement should convert dutch phone numbers to the national format and should replace the + in non-dutch phone numbers with 00)

Comment: Oh well, if the IIF statement isn't usable in sql server 2008 yet that makes a lot of sense haha. Does anyone know if there are any alternatives for older versions of sql server?
Edit: All right, I think I can use a CASE statement instead

Comment: Prior to 2012 I'm pretty sure you can only use `case`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [CASE Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.IpPbxCDR
WHERE   CASE WHEN dbo.IpPbxCDR.OriginationNumber LIKE '+31%'
            THEN '0' + Right(dbo.IpPbxCDR.OriginationNumber,9)
            ELSE Replace(dbo.IpPbxCDR.OriginationNumber,'+','00'))
        END = '0201234567';
```

*N.B I have replaced `[dbo.IpPbxCDR]` with just `dbo.IpPbxCDR` as this would be looking for a table called `dbo.IpPbxCDR` rather than a table called `IpPbxCDR` in the `dbo` schema.*

---

**ADDENDUM**

I don't know if it applies, but the above will not use any index you might have on `OriginationNumber`, which is fine if you are using the expression in the select, but in the where clause as it is it is likely to cause performance issues. To use an index you can rewrite as follows:

```
DECLARE @Number VARCHAR(10) = '0201234567';

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.IpPbxCDR
WHERE   OriginationNumber = CASE WHEN @Number LIKE '00%' THEN STUFF(@Number, 1, 2, '+') ELSE STUFF(@Number, 1, 1, '+31') END;
```

This does all the manipulation on the constant so it is only done once, rather than performing functions on every row. To give a comparison this is the exection plan when running the ablve (top) compared to the first query (bottom):

[image]

**Test Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.IpPbxCDR (OriginationNumber VARCHAR(15));
INSERT dbo.IpPbxCDR (OriginationNumber)
VALUES ('+31201234567'), ('+3469694535'), ('+44208979754');

INSERT dbo.IpPbxCDR (OriginationNumber)
SELECT  TOP 10000 '+312012' + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.Object_ID) AS VARCHAR(5)), 5)
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b
UNION ALL
SELECT  TOP 10000 '+342012' + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.Object_ID) AS VARCHAR(5)), 5)
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b
UNION ALL
SELECT  TOP 10000 '+332012' + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.Object_ID) AS VARCHAR(5)), 5)
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_IpPbxCDR_OriginationNumber ON dbo.IpPbxCDR (OriginationNumber);
```

Comment: I'm actually working on a table dbo.IpPbxCDR in the schema CDR (Don't get me started on the usage of a period in a table name, I hate it too), so I guess the correct way of putting it would be [CDR].[dbo.IpPbxCDR] haha. Anyways, thanks for the input, this does evaluate correctly!